# How to reference the type hint of a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

Is there a way in python's type hinting to say "function with the same signature as this one"?

The following works, but writing out the signature an extra time is required:

```
from typing import Callable

fn_sig = Callable[[int], bool]  # can I get rid of this?
def callme(a: int) -> bool:
    return a > 1

def do_something(cb: fn_sig):
    cb(1)
```

ie I want to write something like:

```
def do_something(cb: Callable[callme]):
```

or

```
def do_something(cb: callme):
```

But neither seems to be valid. (python 3.6.3, mypy 0.570)

Comment: I know it doesn't care. However python has introduced syntax for static typing. This could be used for documentation or static type checking. There is no overloading here. do_something get's a callback with a specified (hinted) signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can retrieve structured data about the signature of the function from `__annotations__`:

```
def callme(a: int) -> bool:
    return a > 1

print(callme.__annotations__)

# prints {'a': <class 'int'>, 'return': <class 'bool'>}
```

From here, you could work on a function that will convert it to the type as you want.

Update: a crude and probably not universal way to do just that:

```
import typing
from typing import Callable


def callme(a: int) -> bool:
    return a > 1


def get_function_type(fn):
    annotations = typing.get_type_hints(fn)
    return_type = annotations.get('return', None)
    arg_types = []
    for k, v in annotations.items():
        if k != 'return':
            arg_types.append(v)
    return Callable[arg_types, return_type]


def example(f: get_function_type(callme)):
    pass


print(get_function_type(callme))
# prints 'typing.Callable[[int], bool]'
print(get_function_type(example))
# prints 'typing.Callable[[typing.Callable[[int], bool]], NoneType]'
```

Comment: Should probably use `typing.get_type_hints()`  instead of `__annotations__`  but.. Is what you're suggesting that there is no stdlib way to do this?

Comment: @ttyridal indeed, edited. re. 2nd: none that I know of.

Comment: This is annoying. While the above is reasonable and valid python, mypy doesn't understand what's going on. there is a reference to template function typing here: https://github.com/python/typing/issues/239#issuecomment-229476174)   but I can't find anything else on the subject.

Comment: mypy is a *static* type checker.  It does not import and run your modules, so it only knows what is explicitly stated in your source code (unless you write a plugin that can provide it the context behind some specialized runtime behavior).